# Which file system to choose for small sized files?

Tags: filesystems

I have a partition and it has ~100 GB of audio files. Most of them are mp3 or ogg, each has size of ~15 MB. I update it on a weekly basis. Right now, the partition is formatted as `ext4`. I have read that `reiserfs` might perform better with small sized files. Would I gain anything from `reiserfs` in my case? Or do you suggest another FS for me?

Comment: 15MB is not a "small" file.  That would be more like 2KB.

Comment: You have to remember people, in the communities, literally just ape established answers.  Which is acceptable, until the knowledge that lead to those answers becomes deprecated. Before `ext4`, more specifically `ext3` + `dir_index`, there were many good reason to use other file systems. today's `ext4`, is almost always preferred over `reiserfs`. I wont deny `reiser4`, it is on the level, but it's not in Linux mainline.  BTW user cjm is correct, 15MB is not remotely small. in regards to a FS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more like a question to [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) communities.
There's some good answers in this article at serverfault: [filesystem for millions of small files](https://serverfault.com/questions/6711/filesystem-for-millions-of-small-files). Nowadays 15MB file could appear "small" to a user but it ain't for FS. Anyway, in your described situation, you are good to go with ext4.

Answer (score 2):

ReiserFS is efficient with small files, but 15Mb is not considered small. With Reiser4 effectively dead, you should look at the space-efficient packing of small files of BtrFS

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem this weekend: 1000000 text files of 5-20 kb. These text files are never changed, so the best solution for me was `mksquashfs`: Today disk I/O is much more expensive than uncompressing 1 MB extra.

It is, however, not a general solution: If you need to change or add files this will not work (In which case I would recommend Btrfs).